# Drawing arrows on curves in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The LaTeX code below  produces

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \definecolor{fogr}{rgb}{0.13, 0.55, 0.13}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    axis lines = left,
    domain = 0.5:4,
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
    xmax = 5,
    ymax=5,
    label style={font=\tiny},
    ]
    \plot[
    smooth,
    color=fogr,
    thick,
    bend right,
    ] {1.578051*x^-1.296597}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image generated using the above code]

**Trying to put a small arrow on the curve to show direction.**

[image: Trying to put a small arrow on the curve to show direction.]

have tried adding

```
\plot[
    smooth,
    color=fogr,
    thick,
    decoration={
       markings,% switch on markings
       mark=at position 1.75cm with {\node{\arrow[fogr]{stealth}}}},
       postaction=decorate
    ]
    {1.578051*x^-1.296597};
```

This is throwing an error as `Package pgf Error: I cannot decorate an empty path.`

Are there any simple solutions to draw just an arrow rather than trying to save the pgfplot first and then trying to draw over it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[fogr]{stealth}}},
postaction=decorate
```

(without `\node`, and relative position 0.5 instead of fixed length).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \definecolor{fogr}{rgb}{0.13, 0.55, 0.13}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    axis lines = left,
    domain = 0.5:4,
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
    xmax = 5,
    ymax=5,
    label style={font=\tiny},
    ]
    \plot[
    smooth,
    color=fogr,
    thick,
    bend right,
    decoration={
       markings,
       mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[fogr]{stealth}}},
    postaction=decorate
    ] {1.578051*x^-1.296597}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```